# Angular 2: Multiple checkbox toggle

Tags: angular

I have 5 checkboxes in this way

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="chk1" (change)="chk1 = !chk1" />chk1 &nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="chk2" (change)="chk2 = !chk2" />chk2 &nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="chk3" (change)="chk3 = !chk3" />chk3 &nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="chk4" (change)="chk4 = !chk4" />chk4 &nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="chk5" (change)="chk5 = !chk5" />chk5 &nbsp;
```

I'm trying to toggle checkboxes. Conditions are-

If the first checkbox is selected, all the other 4 checkboxes shall be unchecked and vice versa(even if only 2nd and 3rd boxes are selected)

3rd and 4th checkboxes must be toggle to each other.

How do I achieve this in Angular?

[Plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/6em820jFfuTuw2NtIFmr?p=preview)

Comment: Was your plan to try something beyond what you have in the Plunk? If you want to achieve something, you need to start by at least *trying* something. SO is not a coding service!

Comment: @R.Richards I have tried and the fact is I'd forgot to save the plunker after my last changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the problem you could create a list of checkboxes:

```
checkboxes = [
    { 
      id: 'cb1',
      name: 'Special (not combinable)',
      value: false
    },
    {
      id: 'cb2', 
      name: 'Example'
      value: true
    },
    {
      id: 'cb3', 
      name: 'Another one'
      value: false
    },
    {
      id: 'cb4', 
      name: 'Toggle 1'
      value: false
    },
      {
      id: 'cb5', 
      name: 'Toggle 2'
      value: false
    }
  ]
```

Then in template you can iterate over this list:

```
<div *ngFor="let cb of checkboxes">
        <input 
          type="checkbox"
          [checked]="cb.value"
          (change)="onCheck(cb)"
          />
        <span [innerHtml]="cb.name"></span>
     </div>
```

The whole check/uncheck logic could be contained in an onCheck method:

```
onCheck(selected) {

    let id = selected.id;
    let newValue = !selected.value;

    switch(id) {
      case 'cb1':
        if (newValue) {
          this.checkboxes = this.checkboxes.map(cb => {
            if (cb.id === id) {
              // set new value
              cb.value = newValue
            } else {
              if (newValue) {
                // uncheck checkbox 1-4 if checkbox 1 is checked
                cb.value = false;
              }
            }
            return cb;
          })
        }
        break;

        case 'cb2':
        case 'cb3':
        case 'cb4':
        case 'cb5':
          this.checkboxes = this.checkboxes.map(cb => {
            // uncheck checkbox 1
            if (newValue && cb.id === 'cb1') {
                cb.value = false;
            }

            // set new value
            if(cb.id === id) {
              cb.value = newValue;
            }

            // toggle checkbox 4 / checkbox 5
            if (['cb4', 'cb5'].indexOf(id) > -1 && ['cb4', 'cb5'].indexOf(cb.id) > -1 && cb.id !== id) {
              cb.value = !newValue;
            }

            return cb;
          })
          break;
    }

  }
```

I hope this helps to solve your problem. A full working example is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/AQsnVMcQilNhqpOM1WMi?p=preview)